# Analyzing the actions of a running program

Tags: networking, memory, debug

Do you know a Windows software (or several) that can analyze what a running program is doing ?

For example, detecting if the program is connecting to the Internet (and to what), of sending data via e-mail or FTP, or scanning files and directories... Or even analyze the content of the memory it is using.

I know there are means to analyze the memory (videogames Tool-Assisted Speedrunners use this kind of software to analyze the maximum character speed, for instance). So there might be softwares that can analyze other actions.

Comment: [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/welcome/?net=search&gclid=CLqh36n7o8ACFaYIwwoduVgAwg) may have what you are looking for it can track lots of different activities if set up correctly

Comment: @NathanTaylor: It seems to me that Spiceworks is an IT Admin tool for enterprises, to know the bandwidth amoutn used by each PC. Can it be used to monitor a single software's activity ? For example, to debug or to detect odd behaviors ?

Comment: The only thing I've witnessed it do as a spiceworks user myself is track the license status of the software, installed version present on the network, and the applications that are installed on each and every machine... im not too sure of the actual background processes that the software runs though, thats why I didn't post an answer.

Comment: What you want is [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). You can use `netstat` or [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) for network monitoring

Comment: If you need to analyze the contents of the memory that the process is using, you'll need to use a debugger like [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/)

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, I will check for some tutorials as those softwares seems really complete to me.
I've heard of [Glasswire](https://www.glasswire.com/) for network monitoring ; what do you think about it ?